# Scipy sparse matrix dimension issue

Tags: scipy, sparse-matrix

I was working on a simple MultiOutputRegressor model with KNeighborsRegressor. My X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test are in Scipy sparse matrix data type.  I have 1185 features and 46 targets to predict.

```
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
kreg = MultiOutputRegressor(KNeighborsRegressor())
# fit model
kreg.fit(X_train, y_train)
>>> MultiOutputRegressor(estimator=KNeighborsRegressor())
kreg.predict(X_test)
```

after `kreg.predict(X_test)` I got an error messages with the last one says

> ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/data3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/sparse/_index.py in >**getitem**(self, key)
> 62                 return self._get_arrayXint(row, col)
> 63             elif isinstance(col, slice):
> ---> 64                 raise IndexError('index results in >2 dimensions')
> 65             elif row.shape[1] == 1 and col.ndim == 1:
> 66                 # special case for outer indexing
>
> IndexError: index results in >2 dimensions

Where did I do wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I shouldn't have my labels, i.e. y_train and y_test in sparse matrix data type. Once I kept them as Numpy array, the code worked.